# Redim with 2D array

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to insert a name and its value into a 2D array :

```
 ____________
| name| value| index 0
|name1|value1| index 1
|name2|value2| index 2 ...
      .
      .
      .
```

What I have done so far :

```
Function ParseCSV(ByVal FileName As String)
Dim FS          'As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim Txt         'As Scripting.TextStream
Dim CSVLine
Dim arrayOfElements
Dim nbErrors As Integer
Dim namesNotInDb() As String
Dim element As Variant
Dim errorMsg As String
Dim namesAgeMatrix() As String
Dim nbrAges As Integer


Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Txt = FS.OpenTextFile(FileName, 1, False)
nbrAges = 0
Do While Not Txt.AtEndOfStream
    If nbrAges = 0 Then ReDim namesAgeMatrix(0, 1) Else ReDim Preserve namesAgeMatrix(nbrAges, 1)
    CSVLine = Txt.ReadLine
    arrayOfElements = Split(CSVLine, ",")
    namesAgeMatrix(nbrAges, 0) = arrayOfElements(0)
    If arrayOfElements(1) = "N/A" Then
        nbErrors = nbErrors + 1
        ReDim Preserve snamesNotInDb(nbErrors)
        namesNotInDb(nbErrors) = arrayOfElements(0)
        instrumentPriceMatrix(nbrInstruments, 1) = 0
    Else
        namesAgeMatrix(nbrAges, 1) = arrayOfElements(1)
    End If
    nbrAges = nbrAges + 1
Loop
Txt.Close
If nbErrors > 0 Then 'displaying error/success message
    errorMsg = ""
    For Each name In namesNotInDb
        errorMsg = errorMsg & name & " "
    Next
    MsgBox "Warning : " & errorMsg & "have no feed in DB. Name set by default to John.", vbExclamation
Else
    MsgBox "Importation success!", vbOKOnly
End If
ParseCSV = namesAgeMatrix
End Function
```

The error I get is : `Subscription our of range` for the following :

```
Else ReDim namesAgeMatrix(nbrAges, 1)
```

How can I Redim my array the proper way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you checked the value of `nbrNames` ?

Comment: Where is CSVLine defined?

Comment: @stobin I uploaded the full code.

Comment: where is nbrAges or nbrAgess defined?

Comment: @stobin That was just a typo when posting it on SO ;-)

Comment: You can only change the **last** dimension of a 2-D range when using `Preserve`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only "Redim" the Last element of a multi-dimensional array in VBA.

The format using an array like ...

```
Variable(Row, Column)
```

is actually backward relative to your process if the idea is you are adding "rows".

You need to reverse your array structure to the below ...

```
Variable(Column, Row)
```

In this format you can define the number of "columns" of information at the start, then redim the Rows over and over.

```
ReDim Preserve namesAgeMatrix(1, nbrAges) ' for example. but you must keep the "1" forever a "1".
```

It takes a little getting used to because Excel and Office type systems and even your natural tendency is to have it structured as "Row,Column"